# MATLAB | Invalid syntax for calling function 'cond' on the path. Use a valid syntax or explicitly initialize 'cond' to make it a variable

Tags: function, matlab

I want to extract data from a table called `cond`. As you can see from line 75 in the screenshot shown below, data `Diameter` corresponding to `Drake` can be successfully extracted using `cond('Drake',:).Diameter`.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ylAW.jpg)

However, when I was trying to write this into a function called `findCF()`, things went wrong at line 78 with an error message

> Invalid syntax for calling function 'cond' on the path. Use a valid
> syntax or explicitly initialize 'cond' to make it a variable.

Can anybody tell me how to modify my code?

Comment: Please don’t post images of code, copy-paste the code into your post. See here for reasons: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/7328782

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cond() is the name of a built-in function.  Matlab tolerates variables whose names collide with functions, but it can result in weird things like this.  In the line that produces the error, Matlab thinks you are trying to call the function cond(), not access the variable cond.

Rename the variable to something else.